# Find a word in a text file and show the starting position of that word in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm Currently working on a college project, in the project I should open a .txt file and get user input word and search in the text file if there is any match , If the program find one or more words it should output the starting position of the words .
I wrote this code but it's not working completely , is there any thing wrong I did or any suggestion ?? Really appreciate that .

````
    Myfile.open("Test.txt", ios::in);
    if (Myfile.is_open())
    {
        string line,search;
        int i, j=0,x,y,z=-1;
        while (getline(Myfile, line))
        {
            cin >> search;
            x = line.size();
            y = search.size();
            for ( i = 0; i <= x; i++)
            {
                if (line[i]==search[j])
                {
                    z++;
                    j++;
                    if (z==y)
                    {
                        cout << i-y << " " ;
                        z -= y - 1;
                        j -= y -1;
                    }
                }
                if (i==x)
                {
                    cout << "     That's all I've Found :)  ";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } ```
````

Comment: What does "not working completely" mean?

Comment: Using more descriptive variable names than `x`, `y` and `z` would help, and these variables should be initialised inside, not outside the `while` loop.

Comment: `i <= x` probably not your only bug, but it's definitely one of them. Should be `i < x`

Answer (score 0):

You may use std::string::find method for that task, instead of writing your own bug-prone code, the method returns just what you need: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/.
If you need to write your own code and not use built-in methods, search for existing pattern matching algorithms, like Boyer-Moore or KMP.